# how to fix mysql data structure corruption

Tags: mysql

`SELECT * FROM ...` works all good till row 653, any operations involve rows after that will cause an error **"ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect..."**. And mysqldump also had the same problem.

I tried to restore the table from .ibd file and end with **"ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query"**

here is what I've done:

1. create a new table `new_table` using the script get from `show create table old_table`.
2. remove the .ibd file of the `new_table` using `ALTER TABLE new_tble DISCARD TABLESPACE`
3. copy the old .ibd file. `cp -p ../old_table_dir/old_table.ibd ./new_table.ibd`
4. restore data. `ALTER TABLE new_tble IMPORT TABLESPACE`

and then I got the error **"ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query"**.

Hope anyone can help me out.

Comment: Copy all rows except problematic one into another table. Then truncate the table and copy the data back. Restore problematic row from the backup.

Comment: @Akina thanks, I tried your method but failed. because once I tried to fetch rows after the "corrupted row", I lost the connection. But I finnaly recovered the table with undrop-for-innodb from TWINDB [link](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb).